# How can I get current document number in frappe (python)?

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

```
doc_no = doc.naming_series
```

Gives me (for sales order) `Order No: SAL-ORD-.YYYY.-` but no actual number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document ID in Frappe Framework is held in `name`

```
doc.name
```

Gives me the right result:

```
SAL-ORD-2019-00018
```